# is it possible not loop the latest_receipt_info to save transaction record in app purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase

Now I am verify in app purchase transaction record, now I am fetch the latest records from app server, should I foreach the records and select database to find if it exists? There has many invalid query, any better way to get the records? Now I am doing like this:

```
  for (Object item : latestReceiptInfo) {
     if (item instanceof JSONObject) {
          JSONObject jsonObjectItem = (JSONObject) item;
          PayTransactionRecord record = payTransactionRecordService.getRecordByTransactionId(jsonObjectItem.getString("transaction_id"));
          if (record == null) {
             mapFieldAndSave(jsonObjectItem);
        }
     }
  }
```

I did not want to query database in a loop. any better way?

Answer (score 1):

database operate in a loop was not a good practice,first you can use transaction id to match the server latest receipt info. If failed, you should try to save the latest record into database(sorted by expre date ms).